# Python: How do I randomly mix two lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, genetic-algorithm

If I generate two random lists for example:

```
N=5
X=20

parent1 = np.random.choice(X, N, replace=True)
parent2 = np.random.choice(X, N, replace=True)
```

Would give two lists e.g:

```
[2,5,1,1,12]
[3,18,4,5,1]
```

How could I make a new list which is a random mix of the two lists with the same amount of numbers?

e.g.

```
[2,18,1,5,12]
```

or

```
[18,5,1,12,5]
```

It doesn't matter about order.

Comment: Is it allowed to pick same number multiple times?

Comment: `random.sample(a+b, N)` would work?

Comment: In a loop; randomly generate a one or a zero; if it is a one pick a random choice from the first list; else pick a random choice from the second list; stop when the item  limit is reached,

Comment: Are the parents necessarily the same length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing your example, you could simply try this:

```
result = np.random.choice(np.concatenate([parent1,parent2]), N, replace=False)
```

Wether to sample with replacement or not is your choice (argument `replace`).

Comment: `parent1+parent2` will add corresponding elements of two arrays!

Comment: @bro-grammer You're right. Forgot that `parent1` and `parent2` were arrays and not lists. Fixed it by concatenating them.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to get a uniform random selection from 2 lists.

- Random 0 or 1 to pick list, then chose randomly in list.
- Random number up to the sum of the lists, then use logic to chose from the first or second list according to that number.

.

```
import random
#### Option 1
for i in range(len(parent1)):
   list_number = random.randint(1,3)
   output(i) = exec('np.random.choice(parent'+str(list_number)+')')

#### Option 2
output_list = np.random.choice(np.concatenate([parent1,parent2]), N, replace=False)
```

The former represents each list equally in the output regardless of their relative length, the latter samples according to the relative length of the lists.

Comment: Option 2 is so simple and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Comment: What does "replace=False" actually mean?

Comment: When repeatedly picking from the list `[parent1, parent2]`, do you "replace" the numbers you've picked (such that they can be picked again), or not?

Comment: No same number can be used twice unless there is a duplicate of the number

Comment: Sorry, that was my explanation of `Replace=False`.  The code above does as you require.

Answer (score 0):

if you are given `parent1` and `parent2`, you can use `np.choose`:

```
which_one = np.random.int(2, size=N).astype(np.bool)
out_array = np.choose(which_one, [parent1, parent2])
```

however, keep in mind that if `parent1` and `parent2` are both random as per in your code, then you could simply do

```
out_array = np.random.choice(X, N, replace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
N=5
select_one = np.random.randint(0,2,N) # Outputs an array of 1 or 0s
mixed_list = select_one*parent1 + (1 - select_one)*parent2
```

If you also want to randomly permute the list elements, you can use:

```
mixed_list = np.random.permutation(rand_fact*parent1 + (1 - rand_fact)*parent2)
```